# Updated to XCode 6, now other simulator destinations do not show up

Tags: ios, xcode

Just updated to Xcode 6, midway through working on a project. Now the only destination that comes up is my own iPhone, which is annoying as I would rather prefer a simulator.

I've already tried messing with the schemes as suggested by other answers and restarted my computer, any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First, you have to download other iOS versions as owenfi suggested, however *that is not all*.

If you want the simulators to show up in the scheme menu/popup, then you also have to open **Devices menu** (Cmd + Shift + 2 or Window/Devices) and add the required simulators. You can choose between all devices and the iOS versions you've downloaded. Have a look on the screenshot below.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Download support for additional simulators in Xcode Preferences > Downloads.

[image]

Comment: Oh good call, downloading now let's see if that works! Thanks! I'll accept if it ends up fixing the problem.

Comment: yeah, if you were only missing those ones (not all simulators in general) I think that should do it. I'll add a screenshot to make it more clear to future generations.

Comment: it said the only available ones to download were the 7.0 and 7.1 simulator, don't know where I'd find the 8.0 one

Answer (score 0):

I never understood but after some installation they don't show up. One easy way is create them  in the devices window. Open xcode go into Window then devices, press the plus button at the bottom left and create yours.

Answer (score 0):

Changing **Deployment Target** worked for me..

[image]